# how to get latest dialed no android

Tags: android

pls help me how to find latest dialed number in android mobile.

```
public static final String[] STR_FIELDS = {
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

// get last entry in callLog

```
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Calls.DATE + " DESC");
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER)));
                }
                c.close();
            }
```